# Tensorflow-gpu + Keras installation error: Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu, keras, installation

I have installed tensorflow-gpu==1.10.0 for GPU usage on Ubuntu but when I call Keras ( e.g. import keras) I get the error: Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime

I have been looking around the web but I could not find a clear answer. This is the error I get:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/boxx/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/boxx/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/boxx/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sltmSV.py", line 8, in <module>
    from keras.models import Sequential
  File "/home/boxx/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/home/boxx/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils
  File "/home/boxx/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K
  File "/home/boxx/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .load_backend import epsilon
  File "/home/boxx/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/load_backend.py", line 89, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "/home/boxx/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/home/boxx/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/boxx/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/boxx/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/boxx/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/boxx/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/boxx/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Can someone point me a method or some documentation to install keras + tensorFlow for GPU on Ubuntu?
Thank you!

Comment: Its clearly asking for the CUDA 9.0 libraries, do you have them installed and available in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH?